# How to run an incremental query

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using Cassandra 3.10 and DataStax 3.1.4.
I would like to be able to run a query that returned data in sets of say 10000 records until the full dataset has been processed, the aim is to be memory efficient

Comment: Model your data that each partition has 10K records. Then querying on a given partition or even search all will load data from minimal nodes. 

I really don't understand, what you mean by memory efficient? You mean on application side or cassandra server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can page the data in most drivers. So for your query you will specify a fetchsize. When you get to the last fetched row in your resultset the driver will automatically fetch the next *fetchsize* number of rows.

Everything you need to know about the datastax java driver pager is well documented here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/paging/

Comment: Partial fetching is good from application perspective only. From a coordinator point of view, requesting a bunch of records in a usually a big no no. If you have very big partitions you'll start to see timeouts well before the first results arrive at application level, because the coordinator will be overloaded (and if it's not then it is waiting for results of another overloaded node that is going to scan a very big partition, but that's depends a lot on the type of queries...)

Comment: Agreed. But as long as you know what you're doing, paging is fine.

Comment: After 30 years of developing with Oracle, ODBC and JDBC this is my first attempt with Cassandra so I am going to rely on the paging functionality of the driver, much the same way as JDBC drivers do. I understand the comment regarding overloaded partitions but not sure how I can influence that, my understanding is that the partition key is meant to distribute the data around the various nodes in order to improve performance.

Comment: That is true. It is also a key on the local node so it can find all data with that partition fast. In the case of paging you need adjust the fetch size depending on how many rows are in a partition on average. You have to measure your own latency values and understand when Cassandra will struggle and when it's fine. Also remember that when you do paging it is very likely that you are putting pressure on every node in the cluster as opposed to when you are specifying a single partition.

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance the size of your dataset (eg 10k records) the best you can do is design your tables around this dataset size, eg create a table and organize *a priori* your data into partitions of 10k records each.

This basically aims at matching the rule "model around your queries".